# Keep Chrome in the background when opening links from Thunderbird

Tags: google-chrome, thunderbird

Before updating to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when I clicked on links in Thunderbird emails, the links opened in a new tab in Chrome and waited patiently in the background until I switched to the browser.   Since updating, Chrome leaps into the foreground when a link is clicked.

What do I configure to make it behave the way it did before?

Details:
ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Thunderbird 45.2.0
Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set your Focus Prevention Level

First install ccsm: (if you already have, ignore this step)

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

... then open it.  You can do this either from the terminal:

```
ccsm
```

... or from the GUI; just search for ccsm or compiz config in Dash Home.

Now navigate to `General Options` > `Focus & Raise Behaviour` and set `Focus Prevention Level` to `Normal` or even `High` if the problem persists.  Close Compiz Configuration Settings Manger, and you're done.